# Adaptive brightness issue on Windows 10 (disabled, not using Intel integrated graphics)

Tags: windows, laptop, display, battery, brightness

I have a problem on my notebook with adaptive brightness. It's issue since Windows 8, but I didn't care, because I had old battery always plugged in, and to fix this issue I had to reconnect AC adapter. Now, I bought a new battery and I want to give it longer life, so I discennect it. Yes, now I can't reconnect my adapter.

I find lots of tutorials, but in everyone was solution "turn off addaptive brightness in battery settings" or "turn it off in intel control panel". But, of course, I disabled it in settings, and I am not using integrated graphics card by Intel, just Nvidia's dedicated card.